# Calculate quantile on grouped data in spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Spark dataframe :

```
 agent_id|payment_amount|
+--------+--------------+
|       a|          1000|
|       b|          1100|
|       a|          1100|
|       a|          1200|
|       b|          1200|
|       b|          1250|
|       a|         10000|
|       b|          9000|
+--------+--------------+
```

my desire output would be something like

```
agen_id   95_quantile
  a          whatever is 95 quantile for agent a payments
  b          whatever is 95 quantile for agent b payments
```

for each group of agent_id I need to calculate the 0.95 quantile, I take the following approach:

```
test_df.groupby('agent_id').approxQuantile('payment_amount',0.95)
```

but I take the following error:

```
'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'approxQuantile'
```

I need to have .95 quantile(percentile) in a new column so later can be used for filtering purposes

I am using Spark 2.0.0

Comment: approxQuantile isn't avaible under version 2 of spark

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One solution would be to use `percentile_approx` :

```
>>> test_df.registerTempTable("df")
>>> df2 = sqlContext.sql("select agent_id, percentile_approx(payment_amount,0.95) as approxQuantile from df group by agent_id")

>>> df2.show()
# +--------+-----------------+
# |agent_id|   approxQuantile|
# +--------+-----------------+
# |       a|8239.999999999998|
# |       b|7449.999999999998|
# +--------+-----------------+
```

**Note 1 :** This solution was tested with spark 1.6.2 and requires a `HiveContext`.

**Note 2 :** `approxQuantile` isn't available in Spark < 2.0 for `pyspark`.

**Note 3 :** `percentile` returns an approximate pth percentile of a numeric column (including floating point types) in the group. When the number of distinct values in col is smaller than second argument value, this gives an exact percentile value.

**EDIT :** From **Spark 2+**, `HiveContext` is not required.

Comment: thanks, i am going to test it , please correct me if i am wrong , the reason i get  that error is that approxQuantile is not an aggregate function?

Comment: approxQuantile is a stat function, indeed it's not an aggregate function.

Comment: thanks 1.is there any way to apply stat functions to group of data? 2. is it possible to create a python wrapper of Hive context?

Comment: Im not sure. I need to test first. hiveContext should be available if I'm not mistaken in pyspark you just need the right build.

Comment: sure i did, thanks , just  the last question : by using Hivecontext and temporary table is our solution still scalable?

Comment: of course, this doesn't mess with scalability. HiveContext is just a superset of a SQLContext with some extra features, UDFs and UDAFs

Comment: getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer.cleaner()Lsun/misc/Cleaner;` error whenever using `percentile_approx` method.

Comment: @Nabid check if your packages version are compatible (spark packages version must be the same)