# Percentiles in spark - most efficient method (RDD vs SqlContext)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large grouped dataset in spark that I need to return the percentiles from 0.01 to 0.99 for.

I have been using online resources to determine different methods of doing this, from operations on RDD:
[How to compute percentiles in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805602/how-to-compute-percentiles-in-apache-spark)

To SQLContext functionality:
[Calculate quantile on grouped data in spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633614/calculate-quantile-on-grouped-data-in-spark-dataframe)
My question is does anyone have any opinion on what the most efficient approach is?

Also as a bonus, in SQLContext there is functions for both percentile_approx and percentile. There isn't much documentation available online for 'percentile' is this just a non-approximated 'percentile_approx' function?

Answer (score 0):

Dataframes will be more efficient in general. Read this for details on the reasons - https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html.

There are a few benchmarks out there as well. For example [this one](http://www.adsquare.com/comparing-performance-of-spark-dataframes-api-to-spark-rdd/) claims that "the new DataFrame API is faster than the RDD API for simple grouping and aggregations".

You can look up Hive's [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) to figure out difference between `percentile` and `percentile_approx`.